# Why don't featured posts from this site appear on Japanese Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, community-bulletin, international-sites, featured-tag, japanese-stackoverflow

I just noticed that Meta Stack Exchange posts tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) don't appear on the community bulletin on Stack Overflow in Japanese.

This doesn't appear to be an issue for any other site I've tested, including all of the other international sites; it seems to be specific to Japanese Stack Overflow only.

See these screenshots of the community bulletins on the [Russian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47OkJ.png), [Spanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoUKJ.png), and [Portuguese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkyPd.png) Stack Overflow sites, and the one on the [Russian Language in Russian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f4ag.png) site. All of them do have the posts tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) linked. The Japanese Stack Overflow site, on the other hand, does not:

> [image: No Meta.SE featured posts]

Why does the community bulletin on Stack Overflow in Japanese not have the Meta Stack Exchange featured posts linked? Was there a discussion over on their meta to remove those links? Or is this a bug?

<sub>Note: while this question is specific to one site, Stack Overflow in Japanese, the SE team has stated that English-language questions about international sites are to be asked here, as the respective site metas only accept posts in the site's language.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be a history of setting "Let's turn off English articles" in the private beta era, since October 2014.

[Community bulletinが表示されていない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/210)

Even at that time, we asked for "Do you want to display English articles?", but we have reached the present without gathering too many positive votes.
It's been a while, so let's check the user's opinions on our site again.

**Update:** As of July 29, 2020, the sidebar on that site [now includes Meta Stack Exchange questions](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3375/19110).

Comment: Also, SE employee aki pointed me to the [current discussion](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3020/meta-stack-exchange%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae%e8%a8%98%e4%ba%8b%e3%82%92%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%89%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84).

Comment: Today SOja's setting is changed; the MSE featured posts are displayed on SOja, too =) https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3375/19110

Comment: @nekketsuuu I just tried browsing to ja.SO today, and it seems they changed the setting back.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Even in my environment it was temporarily hidden, but when I reloaded the page it appeared.

Comment: @cubick Ah, it was caching, as always...